# Import js files globally to vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi I'm trying to import jQuery and THREEJS to my Vue.js cli but I can't find a way to import them globally.

When I try to import them to my .vue file (like `home.vue`) I get this error

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (5:4)

So I tried to import them to main.js using `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')`

But then I get the following error

> '$' is not defined

And same goes for THREE

I looked up online but most answers are about vuejs 2

Edit :
This is my script in `Home.vue`

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(200, 200);
$('.icon').append(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry();
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
scene.add(line);

camera.position.z = 2.5;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  line.rotation.x += 0.0025;
  line.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

This is where I tried to call gloabally THREE and jQuery :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Loading from './Loading.vue'
import router from './router'

window.$ = require('jquery')
window.JQuery = require('jquery')

window.THREE = require('three')


createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
createApp(Loading).mount('#loading')
```

And package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the whole code and package.json

Comment: Done, i edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to define them globally, just require them when you want to use them, in `Home.vue` you should have something like :

```
const $ = require('jquery')
const THREE = require('three')

export default{
name:'Home',
...

mounted(){
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(200, 200);
$('.icon').append(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry();
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
scene.add(line);

camera.position.z = 2.5;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  line.rotation.x += 0.0025;
  line.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
}

}
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you !
I'm kinda new to VueJS is it a bad habit to import globaly ?

Comment: you're welcome, no it's not a bad practice but if you need it in some components just require it inside that components